# ReactJS, passing prop from parent to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have a bunch of components that require the same prop, and going through them individually to add the JSX is cumbersome, can I create a piece of JSX in the parent that will be passed to these child components as a prop?

Here's basically what I want to do:

```
function App(props) {
    /*not part of the actual code, but I want to 
    pass this h1 tag into the  bottom components as a prop*/
    <h1>{props.heading}</h1> 
    <Home heading="Home"/>
    <AboutMe heading="About Me"/>
    <Contact heading="Contact"/>
}
```

I know the code above isn't how you're supposed to do it, but is there a way I can accomplish that functionality?

Comment: As in `<Home heading={ () => <h1>{props.heading}</h1> }/>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. Just assign your JSX component to a variable and pass that variable as a prop. You have the right idea.
For example:

```
var customHeader = <h1>Here's a custom component</h1>
```

You can also set `customHeader` to a React component such as: `var customHeader = <CustomHeader />`

You can pass through `<MyComponent header={customHeader}/>` and in your `render` function of `MyComponent` page, you can simply use `{this.props.header}` to load your component. This can be repeated for any number of components.

Edit based on comments. In that case, I would wrap the component in a function. For example:

```
getCustomHeader = (title) => {
    return <MyHeader
        headerTitle={title}
    />
}
```

Now, in your render function, you can call `getCustomHeader`.

```
render() {
    return <div>
        <MyComponent1 header={this.getCustomHeader("Title A")} />
        <MyComponent2 header={this.getCustomHeader("Title B")} />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Would I need to add `{this.props.header}` to every component I need this custom header for?

Comment: Yes. That's pretty much the case but you don't have to make a new variable for each new header (which would defeat the whole point  as the edit that you commented). You can pass `customHeader` into more than 1 component. For example you can do `<MyComponent header={customHeader} />` and `<MyComponent2 header={customHeader} />`.

Comment: What about if each header is different for each component. `ComponentA`'s header should be "Title A", and `ComponentB`'s header should be "Title B" and so forth?

Comment: Okay, wow, creating a function was so simple...not sure why I didn't think about it. Thanks I accepted your answer.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!